# Are there any languages in the world that contain no sounds foreign to English?

Tags: pronunciation, english, phonetics

Are there any languages in the world that contain no sounds foreign to English? It need not contain all or even most of the sounds in English. Just no additional ones that native English speakers would have trouble pronouncing.

Comment: Might depend which native English-speaking population you are referring to (American, English, Indian, etc), but probably Japanese would be considered easy for pronunciation to English speakers. Hawaiian also has a limited and fairly simple phonology. Esperanto is easy, too, though that's not a natural language. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Japanese and most other languages that contain an R-like sound would be excluded. Hawaiian might work.

Comment: If you're excluding R-sounds (rhotic consonants), then you're largely limited to Native American languages I think.